# How would you authenticate client login using REST method in Youtube

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, youtube, youtube-api

I have this call that makes a client log in, but how do i pass the username and email to authenticate the user. What i am trying to do is get all the uploaded files from a particular user YouTube account. This is the client log in I am using but doesn't work:

```
Dim Str As System.IO.Stream
Dim srRead As System.IO.StreamReader
Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String.Format("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin/Email={0}&Password={1}&service=youtube&source=Test", username, password))
Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse
Str = resp.GetResponseStream
srRead = New System.IO.StreamReader(Str)
Me.XMLDocument.LoadXml(srRead.ReadToEnd)
```

Then when the user authenticates I need to make another request that gets the uploaded videos if the client log in is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to authenticate to retrieve a user's uploads, just a simple GET request on the YouTube API will get you the data in XML:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/<username>/uploads
```

For example, [see here](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/hbosports/uploads) for all uploads by HBO Sports.

see here for how to use the YouTube .NET Client Library to retrieve the videos uploaded by a particular User: 
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#Retrieving_Uploads